# Jenkins Console Output Error: Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I run a jenkins build job for a selenium test, that opens a browser and configures some files.

```
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[1][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022[GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[1][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[2][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022[GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022
```

I am getting this 2 lines in the console output of my jenkins build - I dont know where they are coming from and also my test that jenkins runs works fine (end result of the test = blue ball)

Problem is that i am using a parser, that looks for Errors and it always shows this 2 Errors even tho everything worked fine (for what i can see).

Does anyone know this problem or what it could be

Comment: Searching for that error suggests it comes when exiting Firefox. If you have to use Jenkins console parsing (i.e. outputting test result XML or so isn't possible), then you'll likely have to make the parser a bit stricter.

Comment: Ok, so there is no real fix for this, but to exclude the specific error from the error list?

Comment: The real fix is to parse a test result file generated by the test runner. If you want to parse the Jenkins console log, you should tell the Selenium test runner to suppress its output. Or find out how to get Firefox to suppress the error. Or make your parsing more strict.